# VS Code server(s) for 100 concurrent users

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I would like to setup a configuration for a class of 100 students to run VS Code remotely on a linux server. The purpose of this is that so the students will use a controlled environment to discourage any type of cheating.

First of all, what type of specs would this server need? According to the [requirements](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements), each session needs a 1.6 GHz processor and 1 GB of RAM. Would it be simple enough to multiply this by 100 plus an extra core or two for the system?

Due to the heftiness that this server would require, I am open to running four servers, with 25 students accessing each one. I feel that this would be a better option, but I would appreciate the advice of someone who has setup a similar environment for several users.

Also, on the requirements page, it states that the following:

> VS Code does not support multiple simultaneous users using the software on the same machine, including shared virtual desktop infrastructure machines or a pooled Windows/Linux Virtual Desktop host pool.

I have created a test linux server with two users and both were able to run it simultaneously over a graphical SSH session. Has anyone else used a setup with concurrent users?

Thanks in advance for any advice or input.